# Change Behat language

Tags: behat

I am using behat 3. When I run my tests, all the messages are in italian. How can I change this to english?

```
2 scenari (1 superato, 1 fallito)
8 passaggi (5 superati, 1 fallito, 2 ignorati)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Behat 3.x use

```
# behat.yml
default:
    translation:
        locale: en
```

You can see the full configuration reference via `behat --config-reference`

Answer (score -1):

In your behat.yml, add the line *`language: en`* in parameters.

e.g.

```
# behat.yml
default:
    formatter:
        name:                       pretty
        parameters:
            language:               en
```

For more information, see http://behat.readthedocs.org/en/v2.5/guides/7.config.html#formatter